# Alternative to sleep, semaphores

Tags: c, sleep

I have a simple c program ( on linux). The steps in the program are as follows:

1. within a while loop, It calls a query that returns exactly one record. It is essentially a view that looks for a column called "processed" with value of "0" and uses "limit 1".
2. I read the records in the result set and perform some calculations and upload the results back to the database. I also set the processed column to "1".
3. If this query does not return any records, I exit the while loop.
4. Once the while loop is exited, program exits.

Once it completes running, I do not want the program to exit. The reason is the database might get more qualifying records in the next 30 minutes. I want this program to be long running program that would check for any new records and start the while loop again to process the records.

I am not doing any multi threading or fancy stuff. I did some google and found posts talking about semaphore.

Is this the right way to go about? Are there any simple examples of semaphores with explanation?

Comment: Semaphores are for multithreading synchronization. I can't think of any way that they would be useful here.

Comment: This is an example of the "Producer/Consumer problem". Semaphores (and other synchronisation primitives) at only applicable if you're able to alter both the producer (the external process) and your consumer (your program) to make use of them. They won't help you in a single-threaded application or where the producer is not (or cannot) make use of systemwide IPC. Using sleep is acceptable though consider using a system timer to free up the kernel.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You don't want the program to exit, so don't exit at the end of the loop. I think your real question is "how do I best have my program wait around until there's more stuff to be processed?"

Comment: @Schwern: "how do I best have my program wait around until there's more stuff to be processed?" - This is right. I read sleep is not the right way to wait. Is there a right way to wait in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: I would say that there is nothing wrong with using sleep and poll the DB every so often. The cost is that you are not so responsive, once there is a change in your DB, it may take up to the entire sleep time until your consumer start to process the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I hope you're using a transaction. Otherwise there can be a race condition between 1 and 2.

I think your question is "*How does your program know when there is more information to be processed in a SQL table?*" There's several ways to do this.

The simplest is [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)). Your program just checks every so often if there's any work. If there isn't, it sleeps for a while. If checking is cheap, or you don't have to check very often, polling is fine. It's pretty robust, there's no coordination necessary between the worker and the supplier. The worker just checks for work.

Another is to make the program block on some sort of I/O like waiting for a lock on a file. That's what semaphores are about. It goes like this.

1. The queue is empty.
2. The producer gets an exclusive lock on the semaphore file.
3. Your worker tries to get a lock on the semaphore file, it blocks.
4. The producer adds to the queue and releases its lock.
5. The worker immediately unblocks.

   1. Checks the queue
   2. Does its work.

...but resetting the system is a problem. The producer doesn't know when the queue is empty again without polling. And this requires everything adding to the SQL table knows about this procedure and is located on the same machine. Even if you get it working, it's very vulnerable to deadlocks and race conditions.

Another way is via signals. The producer process sends a signal to the worker process to say "I added some work". As above, this requires coordination between the things adding to the SQL table and the workers.

A better solution is to not use SQL for a work queue. It's inherently something you have to poll. Instead use a named or network pipe. Pipes automatically act as a queue. Producers write to the pipe when they add work. The worker connects to the pipe and read from it to get more work. If there's no work, it quietly blocks waiting for work. The pipe can contain all the information necessary to do the work, or it can just contain an indication that there is work elsewhere (like an ID for a row).

Finally, depending on how much processing needs to be done, you could try doing all that processing in a stored procedure triggered by a table update.

Comment: In this particular example, you don't need to it's transactions since it was not multi threaded and thus no race conditions.

Comment: @AndreasLundgren Any time you are reading, processing, and then updating in SQL there is the potential for data corruption. Another process could connect to the SQL database and start doing work on the same rows you are processing. It's basic SQL data integrity. You don't trust that you're the only process; maybe you are now, but who knows what will happen later? You use a transaction.

Comment: Thank you all. I need to read up on various strategies outlined here.